# Fetching gps coordinates: continuously vs. single request

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview, progressdialog, locationlistener

I have implemented a `LocationListener` activity to get the lat/lon coordinates. I launch a `MapActivity` and want to get the current location and show it on the map. Now I'm confused. What is the best approach to show a progress dialog while fetching the coordinates?

- Start an activity for result (`LocationListener`) and show a progress dialog while waiting for the coordinates to be delivered.
- Implement a `getCoordinates()` method in the LocationListener activity and just call it once i need it (in a thread?)
- Include `LocationListener` into `MapActivity` and let it continuously update field vars from onLocationChanged()

Is there any better solution? I'm pretty sure there is, actually i don't really know what I'm doing right now... :-/

Comment: You should have a look at [A deep dive into location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) from google developer Reto Meier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good model for displaying location(s) on a map can be found on the android official guide.  Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html), and scroll down to "Helping the user decide on where to go".

Comment: Thank You! That's actually the resource i've started working with. But it still doesn't suggest what is the best ways to implement/use the LocationListener.